# How to import files from name automatically in python

Tags: python-2.7

Let's assume to make it easier that I have 10 files named "1","2",...,"10".
Today I am in a situation where i want to load in a script those 10 files, one at a time. 
I am using that code, which is written ten times in a row with in between the mathemical operations I want to use on the Data contained in those files :

```
    Tk().withdraw() 
    filename2 = askopenfilename()
    with load(filename2) as data:

    ..."mathematical operations"...

    Tk().withdraw() 
    filename3 = askopenfilename()
    with load(filename3) as data:
```

etc,etc ...

This way opens 10 dialog boxes,one after one, where I need to type the name of the file to load it ( so I type "1", hit enter, then type "2" in the next box, hit enter, blablabla ).

I am looking for a way to have only one box of dialog to open (or maybe you know something even smarter to do), and type one time in a row the right order of numbers so the script load them one at a time on by himself.

In other words, in a short amount of time I will have 300 files, I just want to type once :1,2,3,4,5,...,300 and hit enter, rather than doing what I described earlier.
Or maybe a way to just type "300" and the script knows he has to look for files starting at "1" et incrementing one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `open` function just takes a string, and you can create that string any way you want.  You can concatenate the static parts of your filename with a changing number in a for loop:

```
s_pre = 'file'
s_ext = '.txt'

numFiles = int(raw_input("number of files: "))

for i in range(1, numFiles + 1):
    filename = s_pre + str(i) + s_ext
    with open(filename) as data:
        ## input stuff

    ## math stuff
```

I assume `load` is your function, and you can just pass this filename in the loop to `load` as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is a very interesting comment.
I think I understood what you meant, and you probably solved my issue.

Thank you !